# Analyzing distributed data using Spark in Qt

Tags: qt, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I have some terabytes data and I want to analyze them in Qt. In a local system, analyzing these data is time-consuming and the best choice is using Spark and hdfs.

I know that I can put my data with `put` command in master node to store them in hdfs format using Qt.

As I saw some codes to execute queries in Scala or Python, I want to know how can I analyze my distributed data like executing some queries or drawing graph and plot or ... in my Qt program?

Comment: Spark currently provides APIs for these languages: Scala, Java, Python, R. (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api.html)

Comment: @JagrutSharma I think there is a way to use c++ codes.

Comment: I haven't used C++ with Spark, but found this link that may help you: https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/faq/running-c-plus-plus-code.html